# Custom shortcut for "My Computer"

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm having problems creating a custom shortcut for "My Computer". Currently I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I used to press the combination <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open "My Computer" on Windows and I would like to keep using that configuration.

What I did:

**System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Custom Shortcuts** > **Add**

But I don't know what commands to put in it in order to make the "My Computer"'s screen appear.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "My Compure";  your home directory? or "Computer". Both are quite different from "My computer" on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `nautilus /home/user/`.

Comment: Or even plainly `nautilus`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the keyboard shortcut for:

**System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers > Home folder**

I have it mapped to Ctrl+Super+N and it properly opens my home folder.